# detect the textbox value by using loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, loops, textbox

now I am doing asp.net and I have 30 textboxes and I different them by using number.

Example:
txtC1Name
txtC2Name
txtC3Name....txtC30Name

I plan to use for loop and test is it its empty but i fail to get the value.

```
int count = 30;
string x = "asd";
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
     string test = "txtC" + i + "Name.text";
     if (validate.isEmpty(test) == true)
     {
         x = "LOL";
     }
 blC9Type.Text = test;
}
lblC10Type.Text = x;
```

what i get is txtC1Name in stead of the value in the box.

anyone know what other solution can do it or where is wrong of my code?

here is my asp.net code in UI

```
<table class="rightT">
        <tr>
            <td><asp:Label ID="lblTaskName" runat="server" Text="Task Name :"></asp:Label>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtTaskName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="lblCreateOnM" runat="server" Text="Created On :"></asp:Label></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="lblCreateOn" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><asp:Label ID="lblSubsystem" runat="server" Text="Subsystem :"></asp:Label></td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtSubsystem" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="lblUpdateOnM" runat="server" Text="Updated On :"></asp:Label></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="lblUpdateOn" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="lblUpdateByM" runat="server" Text="Updated By :"></asp:Label></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="lblUpdateBy" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lblError" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="lblStatusM" runat="server" Text="Status :"></asp:Label></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><hr /></td>
            <td><hr /></td>
            <td><hr /></td>
            <td><hr /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblC1Name" runat="server" Text="Column Name 1:"></asp:Label></td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtC1Name" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox></td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblC1Type" runat="server" Text="Column Type 1:"></asp:Label></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC11" runat="server" Text="text" GroupName="C1" />
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC12" runat="server" Text="y/n" GroupName="C1"/>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC13" runat="server" Text="low/med/high" GroupName="C1"/>
                </td>
         </tr>

        <tr>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblC2Name" runat="server" Text="Column Name 2:"></asp:Label></td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtC2Name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblC2Type" runat="server" Text="Column Type 2:"></asp:Label></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC21" runat="server" Text="text" GroupName="C2"/>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC22" runat="server" Text="y/n" GroupName="C2"/>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC23" runat="server" Text="low/med/high" GroupName="C2"/>
                </td>
         </tr>

        <tr>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblC3Name" runat="server" Text="Column Name 3:"></asp:Label></td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtC3Name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblC3Type" runat="server" Text="Column Type 3:"></asp:Label></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC31" runat="server" Text="text" GroupName="C3"/>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC32" runat="server" Text="y/n" GroupName="C3"/>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC33" runat="server" Text="low/med/high" GroupName="C3"/>
                </td>
         </tr>
        <tr>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblC4Name" runat="server" Text="Column Name 4:"></asp:Label></td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtC4Name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblC4Type" runat="server" Text="Column Type 4:"></asp:Label></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC41" runat="server" Text="text" GroupName="C4"/>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC42" runat="server" Text="y/n" GroupName="C4"/>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC43" runat="server" Text="low/med/high" GroupName="C4"/>
                </td>
         </tr>
        <tr>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblC5Name" runat="server" Text="Column Name 5:"></asp:Label></td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtC5Name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblC5Type" runat="server" Text="Column Type 5:"></asp:Label></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC51" runat="server" Text="text" GroupName="C5"/>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC52" runat="server" Text="y/n" GroupName="C5"/>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC53" runat="server" Text="low/med/high" GroupName="C5"/>
                </td>
         </tr>
        <tr>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblC6Name" runat="server" Text="Column Name 6:"></asp:Label></td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtC6Name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblC6Type" runat="server" Text="Column Type 6:"></asp:Label></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC61" runat="server" Text="text" GroupName="C6"/>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC62" runat="server" Text="y/n" GroupName="C6"/>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC63" runat="server" Text="low/med/high" GroupName="C6"/>
                </td>
         </tr>
        <tr>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblC7Name" runat="server" Text="Column Name 7:"></asp:Label></td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtC7Name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblC7Type" runat="server" Text="Column Type 7:"></asp:Label></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC71" runat="server" Text="text" GroupName="C7"/>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC72" runat="server" Text="y/n" GroupName="C7"/>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC73" runat="server" Text="low/med/high" GroupName="C7"/>
                </td>
         </tr>
        <tr>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblC8Name" runat="server" Text="Column Name 8:"></asp:Label></td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtC8Name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblC8Type" runat="server" Text="Column Type 8:"></asp:Label></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC81" runat="server" Text="text" GroupName="C8"/>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC82" runat="server" Text="y/n" GroupName="C8"/>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC83" runat="server" Text="low/med/high" GroupName="C8"/>
                </td>
         </tr>
        <tr>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblC9Name" runat="server" Text="Column Name 9:"></asp:Label></td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtC9Name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblC9Type" runat="server" Text="Column Type 9:"></asp:Label></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC91" runat="server" Text="text" GroupName="C9"/>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC92" runat="server" Text="y/n" GroupName="C9"/>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC93" runat="server" Text="low/med/high" GroupName="C9"/>
                </td>
         </tr>
        <tr>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblC10Name" runat="server" Text="Column Name 10:"></asp:Label></td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtC10Name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblC10Type" runat="server" Text="Column Type 10:"></asp:Label></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC101" runat="server" Text="text" GroupName="C10"/>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC102" runat="server" Text="y/n" GroupName="C10"/>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC103" runat="server" Text="low/med/high" GroupName="C10"/>
                </td>
         </tr>
        <tr>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblC11Name" runat="server" Text="Column Name 11:"></asp:Label></td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtC11Name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblC11Type" runat="server" Text="Column Type 11:"></asp:Label></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC111" runat="server" Text="text" GroupName="C11"/>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC112" runat="server" Text="y/n" GroupName="C11"/>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC113" runat="server" Text="low/med/high" GroupName="C11"/>
                </td>
         </tr>
        <tr>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblC12Name" runat="server" Text="Column Name 12:"></asp:Label></td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtC12Name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblC12Type" runat="server" Text="Column Type 12:"></asp:Label></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC121" runat="server" Text="text" GroupName="C12"/>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC122" runat="server" Text="y/n" GroupName="C12"/>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC123" runat="server" Text="low/med/high" GroupName="C12"/>
                </td>
         </tr>
        <tr>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblC13Name" runat="server" Text="Column Name 13:"></asp:Label></td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtC13Name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblC13Type" runat="server" Text="Column Type 13:"></asp:Label></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC131" runat="server" Text="text" GroupName="C13"/>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC132" runat="server" Text="y/n" GroupName="C13"/>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC133" runat="server" Text="low/med/high" GroupName="C13"/>
                </td>
         </tr>
        <tr>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblC14Name" runat="server" Text="Column Name 14:"></asp:Label></td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtC14Name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblC14Type" runat="server" Text="Column Type 14:"></asp:Label></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC141" runat="server" Text="text" GroupName="C14"/>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC142" runat="server" Text="y/n" GroupName="C14"/>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC143" runat="server" Text="low/med/high" GroupName="C14"/>
                </td>
         </tr>
        <tr>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblC15Name" runat="server" Text="Column Name 12:"></asp:Label></td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtC15Name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblC15Type" runat="server" Text="Column Type 12:"></asp:Label></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC151" runat="server" Text="text" GroupName="C15"/>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC152" runat="server" Text="y/n" GroupName="C15"/>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC153" runat="server" Text="low/med/high" GroupName="C15"/>
                </td>
         </tr>
        <tr>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblC16Name" runat="server" Text="Column Name 16:"></asp:Label></td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtC16Name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblC16Type" runat="server" Text="Column Type 16:"></asp:Label></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC161" runat="server" Text="text" GroupName="C16"/>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC162" runat="server" Text="y/n" GroupName="C16"/>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC163" runat="server" Text="low/med/high" GroupName="C16"/>
                </td>
         </tr>
        <tr>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblC17Name" runat="server" Text="Column Name 17:"></asp:Label></td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtC17Name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblC17Type" runat="server" Text="Column Type 17:"></asp:Label></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC171" runat="server" Text="text" GroupName="C17"/>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC172" runat="server" Text="y/n" GroupName="C17"/>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC173" runat="server" Text="low/med/high" GroupName="C17"/>
                </td>
         </tr>
        <tr>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblC18Name" runat="server" Text="Column Name 18:"></asp:Label></td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtC18Name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblC18Type" runat="server" Text="Column Type 18:"></asp:Label></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC181" runat="server" Text="text" GroupName="C18"/>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC182" runat="server" Text="y/n" GroupName="C18"/>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC183" runat="server" Text="low/med/high" GroupName="C18"/>
                </td>
         </tr>
        <tr>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblC19Name" runat="server" Text="Column Name 19:"></asp:Label></td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtC19Name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblC19Type" runat="server" Text="Column Type 19:"></asp:Label></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC191" runat="server" Text="text" GroupName="C19"/>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC192" runat="server" Text="y/n" GroupName="C19"/>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC193" runat="server" Text="low/med/high" GroupName="C19"/>
                </td>
         </tr>
        <tr>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblC20Name" runat="server" Text="Column Name 20:"></asp:Label></td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtC20Name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblC20Type" runat="server" Text="Column Type 20:"></asp:Label></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC201" runat="server" Text="text" GroupName="C20"/>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC202" runat="server" Text="y/n" GroupName="C20"/>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC203" runat="server" Text="low/med/high" GroupName="C20"/>
                </td>
         </tr>
        <tr>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblC21Name" runat="server" Text="Column Name 21:"></asp:Label></td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtC21Name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblC21Type" runat="server" Text="Column Type 21:"></asp:Label></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC211" runat="server" Text="text" GroupName="C21"/>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC212" runat="server" Text="y/n" GroupName="C21"/>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC213" runat="server" Text="low/med/high" GroupName="C21"/>
                </td>
         </tr>
        <tr>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblC22Name" runat="server" Text="Column Name 22:"></asp:Label></td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtC22Name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblC22Type" runat="server" Text="Column Type 22:"></asp:Label></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC221" runat="server" Text="text" GroupName="C22"/>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC222" runat="server" Text="y/n" GroupName="C22"/>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC223" runat="server" Text="low/med/high" GroupName="C22"/>
                </td>
         </tr>
        <tr>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblC23Name" runat="server" Text="Column Name 23:"></asp:Label></td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtC23Name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblC23Type" runat="server" Text="Column Type 23:"></asp:Label></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC231" runat="server" Text="text" GroupName="C23"/>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC232" runat="server" Text="y/n" GroupName="C23"/>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC233" runat="server" Text="low/med/high" GroupName="C23"/>
                </td>
         </tr>
        <tr>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblC24Name" runat="server" Text="Column Name 24:"></asp:Label></td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtC24Name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblC24Type" runat="server" Text="Column Type 24:"></asp:Label></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC241" runat="server" Text="text" GroupName="C24"/>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC242" runat="server" Text="y/n" GroupName="C24"/>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC243" runat="server" Text="low/med/high" GroupName="C24"/>
                </td>
         </tr>
        <tr>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblC25Name" runat="server" Text="Column Name 25:"></asp:Label></td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtC25Name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblC25Type" runat="server" Text="Column Type 25:"></asp:Label></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC251" runat="server" Text="text" GroupName="C25"/>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC252" runat="server" Text="y/n" GroupName="C25"/>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC253" runat="server" Text="low/med/high" GroupName="C25"/>
                </td>
         </tr>
        <tr>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblC26Name" runat="server" Text="Column Name 26:"></asp:Label></td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtC26Name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblC26Type" runat="server" Text="Column Type 26:"></asp:Label></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC261" runat="server" Text="text" GroupName="C26"/>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC262" runat="server" Text="y/n" GroupName="C26"/>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC263" runat="server" Text="low/med/high" GroupName="C26"/>
                </td>
         </tr>
        <tr>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblC27Name" runat="server" Text="Column Name 27:"></asp:Label></td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtC27Name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblC27Type" runat="server" Text="Column Type 27:"></asp:Label></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC271" runat="server" Text="text" GroupName="C27"/>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC272" runat="server" Text="y/n" GroupName="C27"/>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC273" runat="server" Text="low/med/high" GroupName="C27"/>
                </td>
         </tr>
        <tr>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblC28Name" runat="server" Text="Column Name 28:"></asp:Label></td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtC28Name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblC28Type" runat="server" Text="Column Type 28:"></asp:Label></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC281" runat="server" Text="text" GroupName="C28"/>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC282" runat="server" Text="y/n" GroupName="C28"/>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC283" runat="server" Text="low/med/high" GroupName="C28"/>
                </td>
         </tr>
        <tr>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblC29Name" runat="server" Text="Column Name 29:"></asp:Label></td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtC29Name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblC29Type" runat="server" Text="Column Type 29:"></asp:Label></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC291" runat="server" Text="text" GroupName="C29"/>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC292" runat="server" Text="y/n" GroupName="C29"/>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC293" runat="server" Text="low/med/high" GroupName="C29"/>
                </td>
         </tr>
        <tr>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblC30Name" runat="server" Text="Column Name 30:"></asp:Label></td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtC30Name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblC30Type" runat="server" Text="Column Type 30:"></asp:Label></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC301" runat="server" Text="text" GroupName="C30"/>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC302" runat="server" Text="y/n" GroupName="C30"/>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioC303" runat="server" Text="low/med/high" GroupName="C30"/>
                </td>
         </tr>
        <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Image/back.button.jpg" Height="30px" Width="30px" OnClick="ImageButton1_Click" />
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton2" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Image/save-btn.png" Height="30px" Width="30px" OnClick="ImageButton2_Click" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton3" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Image/active.png" Height="30px" Width="30px" OnClick="ImageButton3_Click" />
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton4" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Image/inactive.png" Height="30px" Width="30px" OnClick="ImageButton4_Click" />
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton5" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Image/Delete.jpg" Height="30px" Width="30px" OnClick="OnConfirm" OnClientClick = "Confirm()"/>
                </td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;</td>
         </tr>

    </table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use find control method ....

E.g :

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
     string test = "txtC" + i + "Name";
     Control myControl = this.FindControl(test);
     TextBox txt = (TextBox)myControl;
     if(myControl !=null)
     {
           if (validate.isEmpty(txt.Text) == true)
           {
              x = "LOL";
           }
     }   
}
```

Comment: its not working, I filled in all 10 textbox still give me null.

Comment: Shujaat Siddiqui I got this error.. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: i think better would be if u could post it here so that other visitors could also understand the question and its solution.

Comment: and your error shows that your textbox is inside in another control. like update panel or in child page etc.

Comment: i dont have enough population to post picture.